# How do I select a PostgreSQL system column using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Postgresql implicitly defines several columns on every table, such as `xmax` and `ctid` (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html)).

Assuming my SQLALchemy table definition does not specify these columns, is there a way to select them using the core sql functionality (i.e. not the ORM part of SA)?

The following does not work as `xmax` is not explicitly defined in the table definition.

```py
table = sa.Table(
    "mytable",
    metadata,
    sa.Column("col_a", sa.BIGINT),
    sa.Column("date", sa.DATE),
)

s = sa.select([table.c.xmax])
result = engine.execute(s)
```

Specifically my requirement is to reference `xmax` in the `returning` clause of an upsert.

```py
insert(mytable).returning((mytable.c.xmax == 0).label("inserted"))
```

Comment: I now remember I can provide literal sql as a string and sidestep the problem, though I'm interested in any other approaches. `insert(mytable).returning(sa.text("xmax = 0 AS inserted"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to declare `xmax` in your SA table definition as a system column:

```py
table = sa.Table(
    # ...,
    sa.Column("xmax", sa.TEXT, system=True),
)
```

This will allow you to access `table.c.xmax` like any other column (so your proposed `table.c.xmax == 0` should then work). The `system=True` flag tells SA not to attempt to create the xmax column explicitly when emitting `CREATE TABLE`.

(I've used `sa.TEXT` as a bit of a workaround here because `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` doesn't provide an `XID` datatype, and apparently `xid` cannot be casted to a numeric type.)

Comment: Thanks that’s an interesting answer. I didn’t know of the system flag on Columns

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to change your existing table declarations, you can use the [`sqlalchemy.column()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=column#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) function (note the lowercase `c` in `column`):

```py
xmax = sa.column('xmax')
sa.insert(mytable).returning((xmax == 0).label("inserted"))
```

However, if your SQL statement selects from more than one table (e.g. in a join) then PostgreSQL will complain it doesn't know which `xmax` column you're talking about:

```
ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "xmax" does not exist
```

In this case you can use the (unfortunately undocumented) `_selectable` parameter:

```
xmax = sa.column('xmax', _selectable=mytable)
sa.insert(mytable).returning((xmax == 0).label("inserted"))
```

Which works in a joined tables query just as well as in the case where you're selecting only from one table, so you can always use it if you want.