# Get count of inserted and updated records in sqlalchemy's upsert

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a working code of upserting several records by `sqlalchemy`:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

from sqlalchemy import BigInteger
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy as db 

class PetModel(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "pets"

  id = db.Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
  data = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False, unique=True)

  def as_dict(self):
    return {
      "id": getattr(self, "id"),
      "data": getattr(self, "data"),
    }

pets = [PetModel(id=1, data="Dog"), PetModel(id=2, data="Cat")]

insert_statement = insert(PetModel).values([_.as_dict() for _ in pets])
upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
  constraint="pet_pkey",
  set_={"data": insert_statement.excluded.data},
)
ans = db.session.execute(upsert_statement)
```

I have tried to return all rows by adding `returning(PetModel.__table__)` into `insert_statement`, but I can't separate the answer of the `[_ for _ in ans]` statement on updated and inserted. I don't want to add special field to database.

I know that `ans.rowcount` returns the sum of updated and inserted records.

How could I get separately the amount of updated and inserted records using `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: There's the `xmax` hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762732/how-to-find-out-if-an-upsert-was-an-update-with-postgresql-9-5-upsert

Comment: Thank you! It was the step to the right way. I'm using the way describing here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535477/9978223

Answer (score 1):

As `Ilja Everilä` said, one of the decisions is to use the `xmax` hack.

A column with this value we should add to the answer like describing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62535477/9978223)

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert
...
insert_statement = insert(PetModel).returning(
  sqlalchemy.column("xmax") == 0
).values([_.as_dict() for _ in pets])
upsert_statement = insert_statement.on_conflict_do_update(
  constraint="pet_pkey",
  set_={"data": insert_statement.excluded.data},
)
ans = db.session.execute(upsert_statement)
created = sum([_._row[0] for _ in ans])
updated = len(pets) - created
```